# Better way of logging of excluded results with Stream API

Tags: logging, java-8, java-stream

I'm wondering is there a way to rewrite code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> dataCollection = Collections.emptyList();
    final Set<String> someValues = new HashSet<>();
    final Iterator<String> iterator = dataCollection.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final String dataItem = iterator.next();
        // imagine some calculations
        String calculatedData = dataItem;
        if (!someValues.contains(calculatedData)) {
            logger.error("Skipped data {} because of ...#1", dataItem);
            iterator.remove();
            continue;
        }

        for (char element : dataItem.toCharArray()) {
            // imagine some other calculations
            if (element > 100) {
                logger.error("Skipped data {} because of ...#2", dataItem);
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with `Stream` API so that excluded after filters element were logged.
peek() doesn't work in this case, because it either perform action with every element before filter or after it with remaining items.

So far I managed to design it with logging inside lambda, but it seems verbose, awkward and like side effect. We can wrap it inside some method, but it will only hide that code a bit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> dataCollection = Collections.emptyList();
    final Set<String> someValues = new HashSet<>();
    final Iterator<String> iterator = dataCollection.iterator();

    dataCollection.stream()
            .filter(byCondition1(someValues))
            .filter(byCondition2())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Predicate<String> byCondition1(Set<String> someValues) {
    return dataItem -> {
        final boolean remain = someValues.contains(dataItem);
        if (!remain) {
            logger.error("Skipped data {} because of ...#1", dataItem);
        }
        return remain;
    };
}

private static Predicate<String> byCondition2() {
    return dataItem -> {
        for (char element : dataItem.toCharArray()) {
            // imagine some other calculations
            if (element > 100) {
                logger.error("Skipped data {} because of element {}...#2", dataItem, element);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

I hope that there is a better way.

Comment: *probably* an extension of `Predicate` may be? Like a `interface LoggingPredicate extends Predicate...` and a static method `static LoggingPredicate(Logger log)` that would create it and override the `test` method. Just an idea...

Comment: yeah, but ... it's another way of wrapping this code. Of course it has better reusability, than mine

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to do it, since the Stream API does not have anything for logging other than `peek`

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between skipping an item and calling `iterator.remove()`. Such modifications are not supported by streams in general.

Comment: yes, I know. For this question it doesn't matter to modify existing collection, or to create new one. Please focus on logging thing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that skipping is an extraordinary condition, this may be feasible

```
List<String> dataCollection = Arrays.asList("FOO", "hello", "VALID", "123", "BAR", "bla");
Set<String> someValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("FOO", "BAR"));

Predicate<String> firstPredicate  = string -> !someValues.contains(string);
Predicate<String> secondPredicate = string -> string.chars().noneMatch(c -> c>100);

List<String> result;

if(!logger.isLoggable(Level.WARNING)) {
    result = dataCollection.stream()
           .filter(firstPredicate)
           .filter(secondPredicate)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
else {
    Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = dataCollection.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(firstPredicate));
    if(!map.get(false).isEmpty())
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Skipped data {0} because of ...#1", map.get(false));
    map = map.get(true).stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(secondPredicate));
    if(!map.get(false).isEmpty())
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Skipped data {0} because of ...#2", map.get(false));
    result = map.get(true);
}
```

This code uses the standard `java.util.logging` API and will not perform any logging related operation if logging for the specified level is disabled. On the other hand, if enabled and encountering items to skip, it will report all of them at once per condition rather than flooding the log with an entry per element. Using the sample data shown above and the default log handler, it printed

```
Sep 26, 2017 11:00:46 AM LoggingExample main
WARNUNG: Skipped data [FOO, BAR] because of ...#1
Sep 26, 2017 11:00:46 AM LoggingExample main
WARNUNG: Skipped data [hello, bla] because of ...#2
```

The result being `[VALID, 123]`, whether logging for that level is enabled or not.

Comment: Good idea about splitting stream on two. It reactive way of working with data flow. Sadly, in (at least in java) that splitting is terminal operation and it spoils stream lazy evaluation potential. Also now there are 2 code blocks calculating result, which in fact duplication of business algorythm

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think the code in OP is not too bad. Secondly, there are still a bit of improvements we can do by the original code:

```
final Predicate<String> loggingFilter = dataItem -> {
    final String calculatedData = dataItem; // imagine some calculations
    if (!someValues.contains(calculatedData)) {
        logger.error("Skipped data {} because of ...#1", dataItem);
        return false;
    }         
    final OptionalInt element = dataItem.chars().filter(ch -> ch > 100).findAny();
    if (element.isPresent()) {
        logger.error("Skipped data {} because of element {}...#2", dataItem, element.getAsInt());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

dataCollection.stream().filter(loggingFilter).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm not sure if it's: "verbose, awkward and like side effect" to you or anyone else. To me, there is no duplicated code or side effect. and that's pretty much all we can by any language, except some languages may provide chain operation API to remove `if(...); if(...)`.